# Expression for the single common root

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, closed-form-expressions, resultants, elimination-theory

Let $ \mathbb{F} $ be a field, consider the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{F} \left[ x\right] $ and suppose that the polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{F} \left[ x\right]$ have degrees $2,2^n$, respectively, where $n$ is a positive integer. Moreover, assume that they are both *monic* and have *exactly one* common root.

> **Question.** Is there a known closed form for this common root in terms of the coefficients of $f$ and $g$?

For $n \in \{1,2,3\}$ the root is a rational function with integer coefficients in the coefficients of $f,g$.

Comment: You can perform the Euclidean division of $g$ by $f$; the remainder is a degree 1 polynomial whose zero is your common root. This should give an explicit formula (depending on the degree of $g$).

Comment: @abx But if I understand correctly, your proposal is an algorithm, not a closed form expression.

Comment: You are both right. You need the theory of subresultants which have a closed form like resultants (just the last entry in the subresultant sequence). Essentially these subresultants are the successive remainders of Euclid's algorithm. So if there is exactly one common root you get it from the before last subresultant which is of the form $ax+b$ so your root is $-b/a$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Can you recommend an introductory text to the theory of subresultants?

Comment: Try §III in Chee Keng Yap, *Fundamental problems in algorithmic algebra*.

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/321662.321665?casa_token=kUly2D4swrEAAAAA:VaVMGPg-mZCp_zvj7v2DR8pFISzebQJ3oYgVeHlF9da6dLpp8T09_PxzoChK8eLH0xI1t8uDuoLf3Q

Comment: Also note that a worthwhile read is Lesson X of Salmon's book "Modern Higher Algebra" https://books.google.com/books?id=UJUNAQAAIAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover  He talks about derivatives of resultants, i.e., some minor determinants which essentially give coefficients of subresultants.